# Symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

How can I type this symbol in LaTeX?

[image: Strong near]

[image: stong far]

Comment: Welcome! Which symbol? That is, are these 2 symbols, a `\delta` with something on top and another `\cancel\delta` with something below, or 4 symbols? Please see also [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Answer (score 5):

This is just to give you an idea to deal with such thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\wedge\!\!\wedge}{\delta}$

$\underset{\vee\!\!\vee}{\cancel{\delta}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]